# Error: Element type is invalid expected a string(for built in components) or a class/function (for composite functions) but got undefined

Tags: react-native, tabbarios

I am using TabBarIOS in react native,and running it on android emulator, but while using TabBarIOS.Item I am getting following error `Element type is invalid expected a string(for built in components) or a class/function (for composite functions) but got undefined check render method of Approvals`

render() method of Approvals is as follows

```
render(){

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.strip}>
            <Image style={{width:50, height:30,padding:10,top:5}} source={require('./drawable/drawable/asap.png')}/>
            <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:'white',bottom:20,left:60,padding:10}}>Approvals</Text>
        </View>
        <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
            <TabBarIOS.Item
            title="Pending"
            icon={{uri:'./drawable/drawable/approvalbadge.png',scale:3}}
              selected={this.state.selectedTab==='pending'}
              onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({
                      selectedTab: 'pending',
                  });
              }}>
                <Pending>
            </TabBarIOS.Item>

         </TabBarIOS>
    </View>

  );

}
```

The error is in this section only cause if I remove TabBarIOS and place  it doesn't give any error. Please Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: How did you import the TabBarIOS component? This looks like an error related to importing the components.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada import {TabBarIOS} from 'react-native';

Answer (score 1):

When you import TabBarIOS it is imported as undefined, because you can not use it in android app.
Than you call

```
<TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.sele
```

it is interpreted as `undefined`
You better use external implementation instead (something like https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-tab-navigator) or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read the question properly. You're trying to use an **IOS** component for an android app. But you cannot.

The Component with `IOS` and `Android` suffix will only work with `IOS` and `Android` app respectively. If you need to use cross-platform Components then you'll have to use Components without `IOS` and `Android` suffix or use 3rd party Components.

For example, `Navigator` works for **both ios and android** but `NavigatorIOS` works **only for ios**.

In this case you'll have to use something like these:

https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-tab-navigator

https://github.com/alinz/react-native-tabbar